# How to add the String value to the UIImage in xcode,iphone .The code shown represents the images to be inserted in an array

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, fullscreen

How to add the String value to the UIImage in xcode,iphone .The code shown represents the images to be inserted in an array.If i run this code,the list of images to be displayed on the screen and if i tap any one image among the list of images must shown to a full screen.Am new to iphone ,I hope some one help me out with this problem .when appending the second image to the block,retrieving null value

```
    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [images addObject:@"item1.jpg"];
    [images addObject:@"item2.jpg"];
    [images addObject:@"item3.jpg"];
    [images addObject:@"item4.jpg"];
    [images addObject:@"item5.jpg"];
    [images addObject:@"item6.jpg"];
    [images addObject:@"item7.jpg"];
    [images addObject:@"item8.jpg"];
    [images addObject:@"item9.jpg"];

    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
            CGPoint blockOrigin = CGPointMake(x * blockSize.width, y * blockSize.height);
            CGRect blockFrame;
            blockFrame.size = blockSize;
            blockFrame.origin = blockOrigin;
            NSString *imagename=[[NSString alloc]init];
            imagename=[images objectAtIndex:k];

            NSLog(@"image is :::%@",imagename);

            //  UIImage *blockimg=[[UIImage alloc]init ];

            UIImage * blockImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:k]];

            NSLog(@"block image is %@",blockimg);
            TouchImageView * tiv = [[TouchImageView alloc] initWithFrame:blockFrame];
            [[tiv internal] setImage:blockimg];
            [self.view addSubview:[tiv autorelease]];
            k=k+1;
        }
    }
```

Here image is not added to the blockImage.Please give me solution for this.

Comment: After setting the image, just add the uilabel into imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  this , please use NSArray

```
  NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"item1.jpg"], 
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"item1.jpg"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"item1.jpg"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"item1.jpg"], 
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"item1.jpg"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"item1.jpg"], 
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"item1.jpg"],nil];
```

and remove this code

```
NSString *imagename=[[NSString alloc]init];
            imagename=[images objectAtIndex:k];
NSLog(@"image is :::%@",imagename);
```

and again check with breakpoint

Comment: Thanks for answering me, but I got an error here when I changed like this:: NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed: @"item1.jpg"]];

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
This is the error i got and strucked with